# Memory growth when using std::map

Tags: c++

I'm observing a memory growth with this code. But it's supposed to show no memory growth since all the created objects are deleted.

I've implemented the destructor for MyObj and observed with gdb that the destructor is actually called when the map is iterated. 
Can someone explain where I'm doing wrong.

```
map<int,MyObj*> myMap;

for(int i = 1; i<= 500000; i ++) 
    {
        MyObj* pMyObj = new MyObj; 
        myMap.insert(pair<int,MyObj*>(i,pMyObj));

    }

map<int,MyObj*>::iterator ite = myMap.begin();
while (ite != myMap.end())
{

    delete ite->second;
    ite++;
}

myMap.clear();
```

Comment: There are many duplicates here on SO (and should be easy to find explanations all over the Internet with a simple search).  One possible cause of the "problem" is that the operating system doesn't have to unmap the memory pages, in case your process needs them again. If the OS needs the pages somewhere else it will unmap them and your "growth" will disappear.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If I did a delete write after the new it never happenned. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Before and after this piece of code is executed..

Comment: What is the approximate memory that you are seeing? How big is MyObj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Freeing-after-Malloc.html#Freeing-after-Malloc.
Especially the last paragraphs:

> Occasionally, free can actually return memory to the operating system
>   and make the process smaller. Usually, all it can do is allow a later
>   call to malloc to reuse the space. In the meantime, the space remains
>   in your program as part of a free-list used internally by malloc.

If you want large blocks of memory to be returned to the operating system, consider using `mmap`.

Comment: Hi, if I just declare an empty map object(like map<int, myObj*> idx_to_Objp;), then, right after this declaration, does it have space in the stack?  I mean before adding any value to it. (But from above, it sounds like map has space on heap). - oh, I just found map is allocated on heap.